# Should I specify a random_state in any classifier when doing a 10x10 StratifiedShuffleSplit?

Tags: python-3.x, random, machine-learning

I am doing 10x10 StratifiedShuffleSplit. And I average all the accuracies from each fold.
As you can see in the code, I use 10 different random_states for SSS. But for RandomForest I do not use anything.
Should I also specifify the random_state in RandomForest too? 
What will happen if I do not do it?

Thank you.

```
    result_list = [] 

    for name in ["AWA"]: 
         for el in ['Fp1']:
            x=sio.loadmat('/home/TrainVal/{}_{}.mat'.format(name, el))['x']
            s_y=sio.loadmat('/home/TrainVal/{}_{}.mat'.format(name, el))['y']
            y=np.ravel(s_y)


            print(name, el, x.shape, y.shape)
            print("")

            clf = make_pipeline(preprocessing.RobustScaler(), RandomForestClassifier())   
        ##################10x10 SSS#############
            print("10x10")
            xSSSmean10 = []
            for i in range(10):
                sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(y, 10, test_size=0.1, random_state=i) 
                scoresSSS = cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, x, y , cv=sss)

                xSSSmean10.append(scoresSSS.mean())


            result_list.append(xSSSmean10)
```

Comment: Doing it: every time you call your code the same random-numbers are drawn -> same behaviour. Not doing it: time-based seeding will occur and two calls of your script will probably result in different results. That's basic PRNG usage. The keyword is **reproducibility**.

Comment: @sascha So, what random_state should I put in RandomForest? Just a number (ex. 0). Or should it change with every iteration just like SSS is doing?